# Matching playing cards' suits and ranks in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I need some help with the implementation of a Haskell function which should do playing cards matching - i.e. "Ace of Spades","2 of Diamonds", "Jack of Hearts". Note that the plural for "s" cannot be part of the constructor names in Suit.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck#Rank_and_color

Here is my code so far:

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
    deriving (Show, Ord)

data Rank = Ace | Zwei | Drei | Vier | Fuenf
| Sechs | Sieben | Acht | Neun | Zehn 
| Jack | Queen | King 
    deriving (Show, Enum, Read, Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card {rank :: Rank,
                suit :: Suit}
     deriving (Show, Read, Ord)
```

The required function should be of the type "match :: Card ->String" producing a message like "Ace of Diamond+ "s" "

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: match c = show (rank c) ++ " of " ++ show (suit c) ++ "s" ?

Comment: Please rollback to previous version, add a CW answer with what helped, and tick it. Editing the question is not the way.

Comment: @Warditive You keep deleting information from your question that's important to make sense of the answers. Please don't. If someone comes along six months from now, sees a “question” that says only “thank you for your help, I solved it now” and answers that don't make sense because they refer to bits of the question that aren't there any more, that doesn't help anybody.

Comment: This question should remain in its current form. It solves the OP's problem with the content while appearing to retain the meat of the question. Warditive: In the future, do not post something in the first place that will cause you any... trouble.

Answer (score 5):

```
match c = show (rank c) ++ " of " ++ show (suit c) ++ "s"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
match c = rankToString ++ " of " ++ show (suit c) ++ "s" where
    rankToString = case lookup (rank c) (zip [Two..Ten] [2..10]) of
        Just n -> show n
        Nothing -> show (rank c)
```

if you really want `2 of Spades` instead of `Two of Spades`.

A fun exercise is to try and do this in any other language you know (like Spanish or German, not Java!). In Dutch, in certain games, the 9 of spades is sometimes called 'nel'. How would you deal with that?

Comment: For the matter, there's an English language game where the nine of diamonds is known as “the badger”.

Comment: I tried using both @yatima2975's and kaan's suggestions, but now GHCi is producing a weird error when I try to call the match function - "Couldn't match type "Card" with actual type "Rank". I am using "match Ace" for the test...

Furthermore, how could I list all the cards in the following fixed string order "Ace of Clubs, Two (up to) Ten of Clubs, Jack of Clubs, Queen of Clubs, King of Clubs .... King of Spades" using

type Deck = [Card]
deck::Deck
deck = [Card val su | val <- [Two .. Ace], su <- [Club .. Spade]]

?

Comment: @Warditive: You have to use `match (Card Ace Spades)` to test; the match function works on cards, not on ranks. That `deck` looks okay to me; if there's a problem, please ask a new question!